# Create multiple types of images using image functions

Tags: php, gd

```
<?php

$targ_w = $_POST['targ_w'];
$targ_h = $_POST['targ_h'];
$jpeg_quality = 90;
$src = $_POST['photo_url'];

// create new jpeg image based on the target sizes
$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'], $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);
imagejpeg($dst_r,$src,$jpeg_quality);

// display the  photo - "?time()" to force refresh by the browser
echo '<img src="'.$src.'?'.time().'">';

exit;
?>
```

I was making the code for image cropping and saving the cropped image by using the above code. I can crop and save jpg files by using `imagecreatefromjpeg` and also changing the function to `imagecreatefrompng` I can crop png files please help me to validate or save multiple types of images with this code at a time
Thanks!

Comment: Look into [exif_imagetype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php), then make a basic branch to deal with the appropriate image type.

Answer (score 0):

```
$src = $_POST['photo_url'];

$what = getimagesize($src);
switch(strtolower($what['mime']))
{
    case 'image/png':
        $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($src);
        $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($src);
        $type = '.png';
        break;
    case 'image/jpeg':
        $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
        error_log("jpg");
        $type = '.jpeg';
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $img_r = imagecreatefromgif($src);
        $source_image = imagecreatefromgif($src);
        $type = '.gif';
        break;
    default: die('image type not supported');
}
```

Thanks this is the required code for valid any type of image